# Fix preprocessor macro

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, macros

I have below sample code for showing Alert view as macro

```
#define SHOW_ALERT(title,msg,del,cancel,other) \
do { \
UIAlertView *_alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:msg delegate:del cancelButtonTitle:cancel otherButtonTitles:other,nil]; \
[_alert show]; \
} while(0);
```

to call use

```
 SHOW_ALERT(@"Error!", @"Please Check!", nil, @"Ok", nil)
```

I am trying to handle error message according to my string pass

```
SHOW_ALERT_STATUSCODE(@"404") // give error
```

Here is what i tried

```
#define SHOW_ALERT_STATUSCODE(code) \
do { \
\NSString *errorMsg=@"";\
if([Status_code isEqualtoString:@"404"])\
\{errorMsg=@"Page Not Found";}\
\else if([Status_code isEqualtoString:@"401"])\
\{errorMsg=@"Authentication Failed";}\
\
UIAlertView *_alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:errorMsg delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok",nil]; \
[_alert show]; \
} while(0);
```

But it give me below error

[image]

Comment: UIAlertView is deprecated now, see [UIAlertController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014538-CH1-SW2) instead of that.

Comment: Do yourself and the rest of the world a favour and create a function or method. Time to realise that you live in the 21st century now. And if you insist on the do { } while (0) then get rid of the semicolon at the end.

Comment: find out my answer  . . . .if need more help then please comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend don't use macro for this it will make complex code.

Just use a static method.

```
__unused static void showAlertForStatusCode(NSUInteger code)
{
    NSString *errorMsg = nil;
    if (code == 404)
        errorMsg = @"Page Not Found";
    else if (code == 401)
        errorMsg = @"Authentication Failed";
    else
        errorMsg = @"Unknown error";
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert"
                                                    message:errorMsg
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

And you call this static method with the object reference or by using self.
EXA:-

```
showAlertForStatusCode(400);
```

**OR USE THIS**

Use this macro as I have used in my project

```
#define AlertWithMessage(msg) [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Titile" message:msg delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show]
```

Comment: if you get error because of __unused then remove it and just use static

Comment: The alert view delegate is not set.

Comment: you can set delegate . . .

Answer (score 3):

There are spurious backslashes at the start of some lines:

```
\NSString *errorMsg=@"";\

\{errorMsg=@"Page Not Found";}\

\else if([Status_code isEqualtoString:@"401"])\
```

Also you pass in `code` but test `Status_code`.

I would recommend throwing that unweildy rubbish away and instead create a method which is easy to read and maintain:

```
- (void)showAlertForStatusCode:(NSUInteger)code
{
    NSString errorMsg = nil;
    if (code == 404)
        errorMsg = @"Page Not Found";
    else if (code == 401)
        errorMsg = @"Authentication Failed";
    else
        errorMsg = @"Unknown error";
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" 
                                                    message:errorMsg
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:nil 
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

Comment: how to do it as a MACRO DEFINE ?

Comment: @iphonemaclover Get rid of the spurious backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

try this one.

```
  #define SHOW_ALERT_STATUSCODE(code)                     \
  \
  do {                                                    \
  \
 NSString *errorMsg=@"";                                  \
 if([code isEqualToString:@"404"])                     \
 {\
    errorMsg=@"Page Not Found";                           \
 }\
 else if([code isEqualToString:@"401"])                 \
 {\
     errorMsg=@"Authentication Failed";                   \
 }\
  \
   UIAlertView *_alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:errorMsg delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok",nil];                                 \
  \
  [_alert show];                                          \
} while(0);                                               \
```

there is nothing wrong with your code except the leading ' \ '.

Comment: That code won't work. `@"code"` is not what you want, and you also test `@"401"` == `@"401"`.  Also in the OPs original code, he was passing in a string anyway.